# how to map two dataframes on condition while having different rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have two dataframes that need to be mapped (or joined?) based on some condition. These are the dataframes:

`df_1`

```
      img_names   img_array
0         1_rel         253
1   1_rel_right         255
2     1_rel_top         250
3         4_rel         180
4   4_rel_right         182
5     4_rel_top         189
6         7_rel         217
7   7_rel_right         183
8     7_rel_top         196
```

`df_2`

```
  List_No    time
0       1      38
1       4      23
2       7      32
```

After mapping I would like to get the following dataframe:

`df_3`

```
      img_names   img_array    List_No    time   
0         1_rel         253          1      38
1   1_rel_right         255          1      38
2     1_rel_top         250          1      38
3         4_rel         180          4      23
4   4_rel_right         182          4      23
5     4_rel_top         189          4      23
6         7_rel         217          7      32
7   7_rel_right         183          7      32
8     7_rel_top         196          7      32
```

Basically, `df_2`'s each row is populated 3 times to match the number of rows in `df_1` and the mapping (if we can say so) is done by the split string in each row of `df_1`'s `img_name` column. The names of row elements in `img_names` may have different names, but each of them always starts with the some number (`1,4,7` in this case) and an undescore, etc. So I need to split the correspongding number in each row and map it with the row elements of `List_No`.

I hope the example above is clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can just extract the digit parts and merge:

```
df_1['List_No'] = df_1['img_names'].str.split('_').str[0].astype(int)
df_3 = df_1.merge(df_2, on='List_No')
```

Output:

```
     img_names  img_array  List_No  time
0        1_rel        253        1    38
1  1_rel_right        255        1    38
2    1_rel_top        250        1    38
3        4_rel        180        4    23
4  4_rel_right        182        4    23
5    4_rel_top        189        4    23
6        7_rel        217        7    32
7  7_rel_right        183        7    32
8    7_rel_top        196        7    32
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @QuangHoang's answer (which I believe you should pick, as it is more robust). This uses the `map` method, and assumes every value in df2's time is in df1:

```
df1.assign(
    List_No=df1.img_names.str.extract(r"(\d)", expand=False).astype(int),
    time=lambda x: x.List_No.map(df2["time"]),
)


   img_names    img_array   List_No time
0   1_rel            253    1       38
1   1_rel_right      255    1       38
2   1_rel_top        250    1       38
3   4_rel            180    4       23
4   4_rel_right      182    4       23
5   4_rel_top        189    4       23
6   7_rel            217    7       32
7   7_rel_right      183    7       32
8   7_rel_top        196    7       32
```